# Mongoose/MongoDB result fields appear undefined in Javascript

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, javascript-objects, function-prototypes

Is there something that I'm missing that would allow item to log as an object with a parameter, but when I try to access that parameter, it's undefined?

What I've tried so far:

- `console.log(item)` => `{ title: "foo", content: "bar" }` , that's fine
- `console.log(typeof item)` => object
- `console.log(item.title)` => "undefined"

I'll include some of the context just in case it's relevant to the problem.

```
var TextController = function(myCollection) {
  this.myCollection = myCollection
}

TextController.prototype.list = function(req, res, next) {
  this.myCollection.find({}).exec(function(err, doc) {
    var set = new Set([])
    doc.forEach(function(item) {
      console.log(item)         // Here item shows the parameter
      console.log(item.title)   // "undefined"
      set.add(item.title)       
    })
    res.json(set.get());
  })
}
```

Based on suggestion I dropped `debugger` before this line to check what item actually is via the node repl debugger.  This is what I found : http://hastebin.com/qatireweni.sm

From this I tried `console.log(item._doc.title)` and it works just fine.. So, this seems more like a mongoose question now than anything.

There are questions similar to this, but they seem to be related to 'this' accessing of objects or they're trying to get the object outside the scope of the function.  In this case, I don't think I'm doing either of those, but inform me if I'm wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 57, accepted):

### Solution

You can call the `toObject` method in order to access the fields. For example:

```
var itemObject = item.toObject();
console.log(itemObject.title); // "foo"
```

### Why

As you point out that **the real fields are stored in the `_doc` field of the document**.

But why `console.log(item)` => `{ title: "foo", content: "bar" }`?

From [the source code of mongoose(document.js)](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/4.4.10/lib/document.js#L2174-L2196), we can find that the `toString` method of `Document` call the `toObject` method. So `console.log` will show fields 'correctly'. The source code is shown below:

```
var inspect = require('util').inspect;

...

/**
 * Helper for console.log
 *
 * @api public
 */
Document.prototype.inspect = function(options) {
  var isPOJO = options &&
    utils.getFunctionName(options.constructor) === 'Object';
  var opts;
  if (isPOJO) {
    opts = options;
  } else if (this.schema.options.toObject) {
    opts = clone(this.schema.options.toObject);
  } else {
    opts = {};
  }
  opts.minimize = false;
  opts.retainKeyOrder = true;
  return this.toObject(opts);
};

/**
 * Helper for console.log
 *
 * @api public
 * @method toString
 */

Document.prototype.toString = function() {
  return inspect(this.inspect());
};
```

Comment: Didn't work for me on Mongo 3.2. Says it doesn't have `toObject` method.

Comment: @GeorgeRappel By referring the [`History`](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/History.md#340--2012-11-10) of `Automattic/mongoose`, the `toObject` was added at version 3.4.0. The latest version of mongoose is 4.5.2. I think you need to update your mongoose module...

Comment: I have moongose version 4.8.4 and I got the same message error: "TypeError: user.toObject is not a function"

Comment: If i do this `toObject` can I use the obj (foo) as a mongoose object normally e.g. `foo.save()` ?
I soved this problem using the `.lean()` when querying mongoose

Answer (score 16):

Make sure that you have defined title in your schema:

```
var MyCollectionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: String,
    title: String
});
```

Comment: This was my problem!!! The document was correct in the database, but because the schema was incorrect it would not display the variable even though it did print the whole object correctly.

Answer (score 4):

Try performing a `for in` loop over `item` and see if you can access values.

```
for (var k in item) {
    console.log(item[k]);
}
```

If it works, it would mean your keys have some `non-printable` characters or something like this.

From what you said in the comments, it looks like somehow `item` is an instance of a `String` primitive wrapper.

E.g.

```
var s = new String('test');
typeof s; //object
s instanceof String; //true
```

To verify this theory, try this:

```
eval('(' + item + ')').title;
```

It could also be that `item` is an object that has a `toString` method that displays what you see.

EDIT: **To identify these issues quickly, you can use `console.dir` instead of `console.log`, since it display an interactive list of the object properties. You can also but a breakpoint and add a watch.**

Comment: Yes! sort of.  Except when I do this, it returns the object as a string. ex `"{ title: 'foo'\n content: 'bar'}"`

Comment: You mean `console.log(item[k])` displays what you said?

Comment: it displays the item as a string, which makes the parameters of the object inaccessible. I've updated the question to describe better what I know about what's happening.

Comment: @tippenein, I updated the answer so that you understand the result you were getting. I expect that the object had a custom `toString` function for printing itself. That would explain the confusion.

Comment: I appreciate the explanations, but judging by my recent finds, item._doc.title returns what I expect. This confirms that it's an object but an object that somehow doesn't print out what it actually contains.

Comment: @tippenein, Yep, that's exactly what I was explaning with the implementation of a custom `toString` method.

Comment: Dumping the object properties out is a good approach, or inspecting it in the debugger to see what it *actually* contains.

Comment: @tippenein Added some more information to help you tackle similar problems in the future.

Answer (score 4):

**Use `findOne()` instead of `find()`.**

The `find()` method returns an array of values, even if you have only one possible result, you'll need to use item[0] to get it.

The `findOne` method returns one object or none, then you'll be able to access its properties with no issues.

Comment: This was it, thank you!!! Missed to notice I was dealing with an array!

Answer (score 3):

Old question, but since I had a problem with this too, I'll answer it.
This probably happened because you're using `find()` instead of `findOne()`. So in the end, you're calling a method for an array of documents instead of a document, resulting in finding an array and not a single document. Using `findOne()` will let you get access the object normally.

Answer (score 3):

A better way to tackle an issue like this is using `doc.toObject()` like this

```
doc.toObject({ getters: true })
```

other options include:

- `getters:` apply all getters (path and virtual getters)
- `virtuals:` apply virtual getters (can override getters option)
- `minimize:` remove empty objects (defaults to true)
- `transform:` a transform function to apply to the resulting document before returning
- `depopulate:` depopulate any populated paths, replacing them with their original refs (defaults to false)
- `versionKey:` whether to include the version key (defaults to true)

so for example you can say

```
Model.findOne().exec((err, doc) => {
   if (!err) {
      doc.toObject({ getters: true })
      console.log('doc _id:', doc._id) // or title
   }
})
```

and now it will work

Answer (score 2):

You don't have whitespace or funny characters in `' title'`, do you? They can be defined if you've quoted identifiers into the object/map definition.  For example:

```
var problem = {
    ' title': 'Foo',
    'content': 'Bar'
};
```

That might cause `console.log(item)` to display similar to what you're expecting, but cause your `undefined` problem when you access the `title` property without it's preceding space.

Comment: `doc` is the results of the mongo db query, so I just iterate through those objects. I did try item[' title'] and item['title '] though. No luck

Answer (score 2):

I think using 'find' method returns an array of Documents.I tried this and I was able to print the title

```
for (var i = 0; i < doc.length; i++) {
   console.log("iteration " + i);
   console.log('ID:' + docs[i]._id);
   console.log(docs[i].title);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to get the info without all mongoose benefits, save i.e., you can use .lean() in your query. It will get your info quicker and you'll can use it as an object directly.

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean

As says in docs, this is the best to read-only scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Are you initializing your object?

```
function MyObject()
{
    this.Title = "";
    this.Content = "";
}

var myo1 = new MyObject();
```

If you do not initialize or have not set a title. You  will get undefined.

Comment: The object is returned by the mongoose collection.find({}), but perhaps you're on to something. Maybe there is something wrong with my initializing of TextController

Comment: I recommend using chrome or firefox dev tools to place a break point so you can inspect that your object looks like.

Answer (score 0):

When you make tue query, use `.lean()` E.g

```
const order = await Order.findId("84578437").lean()
```

Answer (score 0):

find returns an array of object , so to access element use indexing, like
`doc[0].title`