# mongoose find result can't use as an object when I loop it

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

my collection(messages) has a field(PROGRAM), when I try to print it use obj[i].PROGRAM, it return undefined.

```
var messages = db.model('messages', mongoose.Schema({}), 'messages');
messages.find({}).limit(10).exec(function(err, obj) {
    console.log(obj);
    for(var i=0; i<obj.length; i++) {
        console.log(obj[i].PROGRAM);    //why here return undefine ? 
    }
});
```

result:

```
[ { PROGRAM: 'sudo' } ]
undefined
```

Comment: What's your schema? It would need to have a `PROGRAM` field defined.

Comment: @WiredPrairie like this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18710043/mongoose-mongodb-result-fields-appear-undefined-in-javascript  But I still don't Know why I should use obj[i]._doc.PROGRAM     what is "_doc" in node?

Comment: added an explanation as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use Mongoose, you'll need to define the Schema, and then create the model. If you have an existing collection you want to use, you'll need to model the structure using the Schema definition. For example, if you have a field in a document called `PROGRAM` and it is of type `String`:

```
var Message = mongoose.model('messages', mongoose.Schema({
        PROGRAM : String
    }), 'messages');
```

You'll be able to refer to it then later as just:

```
var msg = new Message();
msg.PROGRAM = 'npm';
if (msg.PROGRAM === 'node') {
   // etc... do whatever you'd want. 
}
```

Comment: You mean that every existing collection if I want to use， I have to define all of the field. Is there any convenient way to use like perl control mysql?

Comment: Don't use Mongoose. If you just use the native driver, it does not impose or support schema definitions. Mongoose adds a number of abstractions on top of the driver.

Answer (score 0):

You want exactly one object to be returned? If so, the following code should fit your requirements:

```
messages.findOne({"Programm" : "sudo}, function(error, obj) {
    // ...
});
```

However, if you want to query all objects within your messages collection, you could use:

```
messages.find({}, function(error, obj) {
    // ...
    obj.forEach(function(o) {
        console.log(o.property);
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry，my english is poor. My problem is how to foreach the result, when I try to console.log(obj[i].PROGRAM), it returns undefined. But, console.log(obj) is correct.

Comment: "console.log(obj[i].PROGRAM)" return "undefined". "console.log(obj[i]._doc.PROGRAM)" return what I need. what is "_doc" in node?