# get _id with mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I was trying to console.log(record._id) all of records on my mongodb collection using Mongoose. I kept getting `undefined` for each of the _id values.

I struggled until I bumped into [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18710043/mongoose-mongodb-result-fields-appear-undefined-in-javascript). Then I used console.dir to find the location of the _id and used that in my console.log:

```
MySchemaModel.find({}).then(function(records) {

  records.forEach(function(record) {

    console.log(record._doc._id); // <-- I added ._doc
  });

});
```

But, this looks down-right hacky. Is there a better way to do this?

NOTE: This isn't just something that affects console.log. I'm just keeping the question narrow.

Comment: what is _doc or how generate this _doc?

Comment: After using console.dir(record) it showed me that the _id property was located in the _doc property. In part, I'm wondering why.

Comment: did you tried record._id;

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to customize/edit record then you should use `.lean()` function.The `.lean()` function will turn it into a normal JavaScript object. If you don't use `.lean()` function then each record is still a mongoose document and `_id` behaves differently in that context. So can use like

```
MySchemaModel.find({}).lean().exec(function(error, records) {
  records.forEach(function(record) {
    console.log(record._id);
  });
});
```

**N.B:** when use `.exec()` then first parameter used for error and second one for success data.

Comment: I still had the same problem when just adding `exec` function. It wouldn't output the _ids, but once I added the `lean` function, then it worked for me. Still feels like this should be more straightforward. Weird.

Answer (score 2):

> Mongoose assigns each of your schemas an id virtual getter by default
> which returns the documents _id field cast to a string, or in the case
> of ObjectIds, its hexString. If you don't want an id getter added to
> your schema, you may disable it passing this option at schema
> construction time.
>
> [Source: Mongoose Docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#id)

```
var schema = new Schema({ name: String }, { id: false });
var Page = mongoose.model('Page', schema);
var p = new Page({ name: 'mongodb.org' });
console.log(p.id); // '50341373e894ad16347efe01'
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess the issue is with .then promise, I have never seen that.

```
MySchemaModel.find({}).then
```

So just try simple  .exec call with callback.

```
MySchemaModel.find({}).exec(function(records) {
    records.forEach(function(record) {
    console.log(record._id);
  });
});
```

Comment: I switched out the .then for exec and it turns out using the "promise" syntax is just fine, so this is not the problem. using `lean()` as shaishab roy mentions is used to strip out any of mongoose's extra stuff, so _id then can get logged.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that each record is still a mongoose document and _id behaves differently in that context. The .lean() function will turn it into a normal JavaScript object.

```
MySchemaModel.find({}).lean().then(function(records) {
  records.forEach(function(record) {
    console.log(record._id);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also use the .map() method :

```
MySchemaModel.find({}).exec(function(records) {
    console.log(records.map(record => record._id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a model you don't get the full object but an instance of `_doc` as record
so you should directly

```
console.log(record._id)
```

or

```
console.log(record._id.valueOf())
```

but when you return record as response you get the full object so it's better to use `.find().lean()`