# Password value returns undefined, but when console.log is used to display it, the user can see it

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, passport.js

So I am using passport.js for the basic local login stratergy.

The code below is what I am using

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password'
  },
  function(username, password, cb) {
    'use strict';    
    UserModel.findOne({
      email: username
    }).populate('organisation').exec(function(err, user) {
      if (err) {
        return cb(err);
      }

      console.log( user );

      if (!user) {
        return cb(null, false, {
          message: 'Incorrect email.'
        });
      }

      console.log( user );
      console.log( user.password );

      if (!bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password) /* true */ ) {
        console.log('password incorrect');
        return cb(null, false, {
          message: 'Incorrect passowrd.'
        });
      }

      return cb(null, user);
    });
  }));
```

Now the `console.log(user)` displays the below (redacted to save info)

```
{ _id: 5d9c8c4ac50eb00cf494bf8d,
  date: 2019-10-08T13:16:58.037Z,
  forename: 'forename',
  surname: 'surname',
  email: 'test@example.com',
  password:
   '$2a$10$ZUtnlBtXsnvw5k517LRYhORPwG.U.2TzCsIwpzM46jLPpMX4iFf4K',
  organisation: null,
  __v: 0 }
```

However the the `console.log( user.password )` returns undefined, and I'm really confused as to why!

Comment: may be the getter has been modified ?

Comment: can you do typeof(user)

Comment: @Sudhakar `typeof user` returns object

Comment: able to access other fields?

Comment: @Sudhakar no, I just tried  `console.log( user.email )` and that also return undefined but the object is still being output as the original post.

Comment: do user = JSON.parse(user) and try access fields

Comment: @Sudhakar do you mean `JSON.parse(user)` Just tried, but doesn't like the mongodb _id

Answer (score 0):

[Mongoose/MongoDB result fields appear undefined in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18710043/mongoose-mongodb-result-fields-appear-undefined-in-javascript)

found the above to work `user.toObject();`

However I didn't have to do this initially it just worked, so unsure whats happened.

Is there some specific reason I now have to call `toObject()` that someone could help point out?