# Why is the value of a specific key for a doc getting 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, mongoose

So I have a function that calls a Mongoose query which yields an array of docs.
I loop over this array in a second time to get the information of each document and compute some metrics based on the info.

Here's a sample of the docs I get:

```
{ _id: 5decefed6575f603068d2213, asking: '3,000.00', currency: 'usd' }
{ _id: 5decefed6575f603068d2268, asking: '1,885.00', currency: 'usd' }
{ _id: 5decefed6575f603068d2247, asking: '2,950.00', currency: 'usd' }
{ _id: 5decefed6575f603068d2291, asking: '3,995.00', currency: 'usd' }
{
  _id: 5decefed6575f603068d210a,
  year: '2012',
  asking: '8,000.00',
  currency: 'eur'
}
{ _id: 5decefed6575f603068d2122 }
{ _id: 5decefed6575f603068d2218 }
{ _id: 5decefed6575f603068d221a }
{ _id: 5decefed6575f603068d2142, asking: '5,000.00', currency: 'eur' }
{ _id: 5decefed6575f603068d2209, year: '2014' }
```

As you can see, some have a `year`, `asking` and `currency` key others just an `_id`. The problem is that when I try to extract the year out of the `Object` it gives me `undefined` whilst, I have no problem at all extracting the `asking` information.

Here's the loop:

```
for (let j = 0; j < docs.length; j++) {
    let currDoc = docs[j];
    console.log(currDoc); // LINE MEANT FOR DEBUGGING. IT WORKS AND YIELDS THE INFORMATION I USED IN THE SAMPLE BUT WHEN CHANGING THIS TO "currDoc.year" I GET 'undefined".
    if (currDoc.asking) {
        countPrices++;
        sumPrices += Number(currDoc.asking.replace(',', ''));
    }
    if (currDoc.year) {
        console.log(currDoc.year);
        distanceYears = Number(new Date().getFullYear()) - Number(currDoc.year);
        countYears++;
        sumYears += distanceYears;
        console.log('\n' + currMake + ': ' + currModel + '\n\tYear:' + currDoc.year + '\n\tDistance: ' + distanceYears + '\n\tcountYears: ' + countYears);
        // <--- PREVIOUS LINE MEANT FOR CONTROL AND DEBUGGING: NEVER APPEARS BECAUSE THE CONDITION ALWAYS FAIL -- undefined
    }
}
```

Why am I unable to get the year information but the asking information I get without blinking an eye?

EDIT: 
Here's the Schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var listingSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: {type: String, require: true},
  location: {type: String, require: true},
  date: {type: Date, require: true},
  asking: {type: String},
  currency: {type: String},
  condition: {type: String, require: true},
  path: {type: String, require: true},
  category: {type: String, require: true},
  make: {type: String, require: true},
  model: {type: String, require: true},
  listingNumber: {type: String, require: true},
  catFrom: {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Subcategory', require: true},
}, {strict: false});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Listing', listingSchema);
```

and the solution to my problem: 
[Mongoose/MongoDB result fields appear undefined in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18710043/mongoose-mongodb-result-fields-appear-undefined-in-javascript/36385954#36385954)

Convert the doc to Object...

Comment: Might be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36385954/12634779

Comment: Actually more than relevant, that's the answer! Thanks for passing by...

Comment: Can you add the schema code?

Comment: @Ardzii the solution is in the second answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/30924760/11129751, you must add the `year` to the schema

Comment: Since the Objects I save to the DB are highly volatile, I'd rather not include this key specifically. Translating the docs to .toObject() works for me I think I'll keep working with this for now.