# Moongose after find, object.map is not returning key

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I have a code that after find and populate, I will then add a new key ('order_date') based on createdAt.

```
const summaryGetOrders = async (start_date, end_date) => {
  let orders = await Order.find({ createdAt: { $gte: new Date(start_date), $lt: new Date(end_date) } }).populate(
    'orderdetails_id'
  );

  await Promise.all(
    orders.map(async (i, index) => {
      i.order_date = i.createdAt;
      // orders[index] = i
      // orders[index].order_date = i.createdAt
    })
  );

  console.log(orders);

  return orders;
};
```

I have checked with console.log(i.createdAt), it do have the date element in the i, but when I do console.log(orders), it is not retunring me order_date.

Is it caused by the async await function? I am doing this because my express boilerplate automatically removes the createdAt key via the toJSON function on my model. I wish not to modify because my code is tailor not to deal with createdAt.

Comment: `i.order_date = i.createdAt;` is just an assignment. Why you use promise?

Comment: Because as of what I know, map is a async function, I wanted to wait it. so I put the promise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Mongoose queries return an instance of the Mongoose Document class, not plain old JavaScript objects (POJOs) so some fields that isn't defined in the schema will not show when you console.log it (You can check for more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18710043/mongoose-mongodb-result-fields-appear-undefined-in-javascript)).

To solve that, you can use [.lean()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#query_Query-lean) on your query to make the result become plain javascript objects.

Beside, you don't need to use `Promise.all` because map is not asynchronous and using `forEach` may be better in this case.

```
const summaryGetOrders = async (start_date, end_date) => {
  let orders = await Order.find({ createdAt: { $gte: new Date(start_date), $lt: new Date(end_date) } }).populate(
    'orderdetails_id'
  ).lean();


  orders.forEach((i, index) => {
    i.order_date = i.createdAt;
    // orders[index] = i
    // orders[index].order_date = i.createdAt
  })

  console.log(orders);

  return orders;
};
```

Comment: Thank you, solved my problem. Worked right away, just wondering, when should I actually use .map?

Comment: You should use map when you need to *create a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array* as mentioned in the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 1):

You missing the '()' in return function so that it not return new value you defined in map. try this

```
const summaryGetOrders = async (start_date, end_date) => {
  let orders = await Order.find({ createdAt: { $gte: new Date(start_date), $lt: new Date(end_date) } }).populate(
    'orderdetails_id'
  );

  await Promise.all(
    orders.map(async (i, index) => ({
      i.order_date = i.createdAt;
      // orders[index] = i
      // orders[index].order_date = i.createdAt
    }))
  );

  console.log(orders);

  return orders;
};
```

Comment: Hi, it is saying
i.order_date = i.createdAt
       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'

Comment: @user5109293123 try this: ```order_date : i.createdAt```

Answer (score 1):

`orders.map` will return a new array. `orders` variable itself will not be changed. So whatever you are adding is in the new array. Check this.

```
await Promise.all(
    orders = orders.map(async (i, index) => ({
      i.order_date = i.createdAt;
      // orders[index] = i
      // orders[index].order_date = i.createdAt
    }))
);
```

Now, you orders will be reassigned to the new array and you can get the values in it.